# Handling error with foreach and explode PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, explode

Hi guys i am handling an error with a foreach and a explode in php.
I don't know why is this happening only with the first two lines of the text area.

My code is the following:

```
<?php
   if(isset($_POST["button"])){
        $btn=$_POST["button"];
        if($btn=="Cargar horarios"){
            $input = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST["lineas"]);
            $linea = explode("NO ?", $input);
            foreach($linea as $element){
                $datos = explode(" ", $element);
                $fecha = $datos[0];
                $hora = $datos[1];
                $empleado_key = $datos[2];

                $sql = "SELECT * FROM jornada WHERE jornada_fecha='$fecha' AND empleados_key='$empleado_key'";
                $result = $conn->query($sql);
                if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
                    $sql = "UPDATE jornada SET jornada_salida='$hora' WHERE jornada_fecha='$fecha' AND empleados_key='$empleado_key'";
                    if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
                    } else {
                        echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
                    }
                } else {
                    $sql = "INSERT INTO jornada (jornada_fecha, jornada_entrada, empleados_key) VALUES ('$fecha', '$hora', '$empleado_key')";
                    if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
                    } else {
                        echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
                    }
                }

            }
        }
    }
?>
```

The text I place in the textarea is the following:

```
18/08/2016 08:00 34415 NO ?
18/08/2016 17:56 34415 NO ?
16/08/2016 07:56 34415 NO ?
16/08/2016 14:56 34415 NO ?
17/08/2016 07:56 34415 NO ?
17/08/2016 15:56 34415 NO ?
```

On submit this displays the following error:

```
Undefined offset: 1 in /home/bgxryqet/public_html/sistema/horarios/cargar-horarios.php on line 88
Undefined offset: 2 in /home/bgxryqet/public_html/sistema/horarios/cargar-horarios.php on line 89
```

After submit it creates an empty row in my db, and the firts two rows are not working properly, here is an image of how does my db looks like after submit:

[image]

I have tried to explode on line break, but it didn't worked for me.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use manual escaping and string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you will create severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) if you ever forget to properly escape something.

Answer (score 1):

You're producing too many array elements

```
$linea = explode("NO ?", $input);
```

So let's `var_dump` this

> array(7) {
>  [0]=> string(23) "18/08/2016 08:00 34415 " [1]=> string(24) " 18/08/2016 17:56 34415 " [2]=> string(24) " 16/08/2016 07:56 34415 " [3]=> string(24) " 16/08/2016 14:56 34415 " [4]=> string(24) " 17/08/2016 07:56 34415 " [5]=> string(24) " 17/08/2016 15:56 34415 " [6]=> string(0) "" }

Note `array(7)` (you have 6 elements) and `[6]=> string(0) ""`

What you should do is split this by the newlines instead

```
$linea = explode("\n", $input);
```

Should give you 6 elements and avoid the error. Either way, you shouldn't blindly trust the data. Make sure you're getting the data right before you try to insert

Comment: First of all thanks for the quick response. I have already tried this, but i didn't realise that $conn->real_escape_string was removing the line break of my text. I have solved the problem as i said before, by removing from my code $conn->real_escape_string and adding your suggestion.